# How to know how many users already joined in a community of Stack exchange?

Tags: support, user-accounts, users

I am wondering whether there is a way to see the total number of users that have already joined in a community of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different ways for finding out the number of users of a site.

- As mentioned already in a comment, [the list of sites in the SE homepage](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#users) contains info about the number of users joined. You can hover over the number to see the exact number.
- There is this SEDE, or Stack Exchange Data Explorer, updated every Sunday morning, that you can play with to find out the number of users, or the number that have joined in a specific date range. See [Number of users created per month](https://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/645132/number-of-users-created-per-month), [Number of users by country](https://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/634786/number-of-users-by-country) and [Average number of users who mention "Python" in *about me* and have a picture](https://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/612418/average-number-of-users-who-mention-python-in-about-me-and-have-a-picture) for example.

There's also, if I recall correctly, the number of users of a site displayed to a certain group of people when showing site stats, but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: all options mentioned only show currently known registered users. Not users that once created but now deleted their accounts or accounts that should have been deleted already: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296970/578411

Comment: @rene the flower thanks for the info.

Comment: If you want the number of registered users that have ever been created: Users -> new users -> created -> user # of the first one in the list.